# mongodb Aggregate query to mapreduce query translation

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am trying to convert to one mongodb aggregation query to Mapreduce mongo query. I'm new to mapreduce . not able to do so. can help would be appreciated.

```
    db.Test.aggregate(
{$group:{"_id":{Source:"$SourceId",Destination:"$DestinationId"},"Count":{"$sum":1}}},
{$sort:{"Count":-1}}
)
```

Comment: Why? MapReduce runs JavaScript interpretation and will basically run much slower. There are other reasons not to use mapReduce case along with the general *"If it can be done with aggregate then do it that way"*. Also you want to "sort on the count". So I can basically say that mapReduce **will not** do that. It has no "seperate" sort stage. All output is sorted by the order of keys produced. And really, that's just an artifact rather than a feature. If this is just an excercise, then **try something**. It's not really difficult. Apart from the sort of course.

Comment: @NeilLunn the reason i'm trying to do this cause i am trying to use this with R through a package mongolite. but this same query does not returns  any result through mongolite where using the same query in mongo shell does gives me output. so wanted to test if mapreduce thing works with the mongolite package of r .

Comment: Would it not have been better to ask the question about trying to do this in mongolite then? A quick google search for me immediately leads me to questions and answers like [mongolite - correct syntax for aggregate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271799/mongolite-correct-syntax-for-aggregate-method). For which I would consider a far more productive use of time than trying to convert this to mapReduce. If you still want to try it then I did say it's really trivial and you should be able to work it out yourself with very little effort.

Comment: Yes it would have been. I have already opened one issue with the author in github. Meanwhile i thought i will check the other alternative.